# What is a result table in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

What is  a result table in SQL?

Comment: In a query which returns a table or store in a temp table named result for getting final result. Also called result-set.

Comment: A SQL `SELECT` query produces a 2-dimensional set of rows as its result, which is by its nature tabular in structure (2D grid of columns, rows). That's probably all they are referring to -- the "result" is the rowset produced by a SELECT query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All query operations in SQL take tabular data as input and return tabular data as a result.

For instance, `SELECT/FROM` operations filter a table into another table structure based on a condition, `JOIN`s provide set operations between tables, `GROUP` provides aggregation, and so on. Yet, regardless of their purpose they all return *tables*

In SQL speak these "table-like" structures are often referred to as "result tables" or "derived tables" or sometimes "data frames". However, for all intents and purposes they're just tables.

Comment: I don't think it's quite right to say that all SQL operations output tabular data.  While some engines can output the results of rows affected, generally speaking non-query commands (UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT) do not return any result.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but I'm talking about query operations. The fundamental strength of the SQL language is that it can be extremely expressive using very few operators by always acting on like types.

Comment: Got it, the edit is a little more clear now... easy for newbs to get tripped up with this stuff.  Cheers